# How to install FFmpeg 4 on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, debian-stretch

I want to update my FFmpeg package on Debian 9. the stretch version is FFmpeg (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) so I tried to add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list

> deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free deb-src
>   http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free

Then I run these commands

> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
>
> $ ffmpeg -version

But I got FFmpeg 3.3.9

Can someone help me to upgrade to FFmpeg 4? I feel that I am not very far from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

John Van Sickle maintains static builds of FFmpeg, that can be downloaded at [his site](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). They carry all dependencies so there is no installation apart from copying the executable binary(-ies if you also want ffprobe and friends).

The current version as of today is 4.2